# extract some arabic/persian (unicode) words with regex using python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x, python-re

I need to extract some specific names in Arabic/Persian (something like proper nouns in English), using python `re` library.

example (the word "شرکت" means "company" and we want to extract what the company name is):

```
input: شرکت تست گستران خلیج فارس
output: تست گستران خلیج فارس
```

I've seen [[this answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939585/2258268) and it would be fine to replace "university" with "شرکت" in that example but I don't understand how to find the keywords by regex with Arabic Unicode when it's not possible to use that in this way:

```
re.match("شرکت", "\u0634\u0631\u06A9\u062A") # returns None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 does not default to parsing unicode literals (like when pasting unicode letters, or having a `\u` in the code). You have to be explicit about it:

```
re.match(u"شرکت", u"\u0634\u0631\u06A9\u062A")
```

Otherwise, the Arabic will be translated to the actual bytes, which are different then the unicode code-points, and the Unicode string on the right will have literal backslashes since Python 2 does not recognize `\u` as a valid escape by default.

Another option is to import from the future - in Python 3 everything is initially parsed as unicode, making that `u"..."` somewhat obsolete:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

will make unicode literals be parsed correctly with no `u""`.